# Questions related to speed of memory modules in a Lenovo T410 or T510

Tags: memory

I need some help to understanding the memory and CPU/chipset-part of [these Lenovo T410 & T510 specs](http://www.lenovo.com/us/en/PDFs/ThinkPad_T410_T510_Datasheet.html):

> Memory:
>
> - Up to 6GB 1067MHz DDR3 (4GB 1333MHz + 2GB 1067MHz)
> - Up to 8GB 1333MHz DDR4 (4GB 1333MHz x2)
>
> CPU/Chipset:
>
> - Intel® Core™ 2 Duo i5-520M i5 (2.4GHz, 3MB L3, 1066MHz FSB, 35W)
> - Intel® Core™ 2 Duo i5-540M i5 POP2 (2.53GHz, 3MB L3, 1066MHz FSB, 35W)
> - Intel® Core™ 2 Duo i7-620M -i7 (2.66GHz, 4MB L3, 1066MHz FSB, 35W)

These are my questions:

1. Why do they suggest to use memory modules of different speeds?
2. I thought it could damage the computer, if I use memory modules of different speeds. Is that incorrect?
3. I thought the CPU/Chipset limited the memory. Could the RAM be utilized the speed of 1333Mhz when the CPU/Chipset has a limitation at 1067MHz?
4. Is DDR4 a typo?

I do not agree that the suggested duplicate answers all my questions. My questions are related to the linked specification.

Comment: [DDR4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM) is not a typo.

Comment: Why do they suggest to use different speeds? Wouldn't it be better to use the same speed for both memorys? @JakeGould

Comment: I don't think the suggested duplicate is one.  This question has four parts and the other question deals with only one of those.

Comment: @user1766169 - They are not the same speed because both are not the same type of memory.  Different standard means different frequencies are possible.  You won't be able to use both DDR3 and DDR4 modules so the frequency of the memory would be the same.

Comment: @JakeGould - Your statement you can't use a slower module in a slot designed for faster memory is a little confusing.  If you put in memory that runs faster then the slot, the memory would be underclocked, more then likely.  Likewise if you are putting in memory in a slot that is slower then the module, the module would run at its native speed, I suppose your statement is confusing since the frequencies are just to similar.

Comment: I am starting to question the legitimacy of the specification sheet honestly.  The chipset this CPU uses does not support DDR3 and DDR4.  The current generation does have this support but its still one or the other capability.

Answer (score 0):

I got some answers from the Lenovo support. "That's a funny page you found there..." was there first comment.

These are the answers I got:

1. Not clear why.
2. No answer.
3. You can use 1333Hhz memory, but it will "downgrade" to 1066Hhz speed.
4. Yes.